# Why the breakpoint is never reached?

Tags: c, loops

Consider below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Makes you guess a number and predicts it.
 */

int main(void)
{
short guess=0;
_Bool first_time="TRUE";
printf("Guess a number from 1 to 100\n");
printf("Lemme guess it\n");
printf("Press n if the guess is wrong, y otherwise\n");
    do
    {
      if (first_time)
      {
        first_time="FALSE";
      }
      else
      {
        printf("Break point"); // This point is never reached while execution
        while (getchar() != '\n')
        ; // Waste the buffer till the newline character
      }
      printf("\nMy guess : %d",++guess); 
      printf("\nAm i right ? ");

    }while( getchar() != 'y' );
return 1;
}
```

My instinct says the breakpoint should be reached from the second iteration 
of the `do-while` loop. But it is not happening.

Could anybody explain why?

**Note:**

Compiler : gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)

Comment: You should get warnings when compiling this. What do they say?

Comment: @JohnKugelman : `-Wall` with gcc gives me no warnings.

Comment: It's surprising to me, but I've confirmed that clang on darwin doesn't warn, even with --Wall.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/288967/bool-accepts-int-literals-char-literals-string-literals-why explains why there's no warning.

Comment: @PaulHankin : Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a string to a type which is of _Bool type. You probably have got warning which says that you are assigning a pointer to an integer type, or something like that. You should use 0 or 1 for _Bool type.

Comment: C does not have a string type. And there is no pointer assigned. The string literal is a `char []` which decays to a pointer to the first element, i.e. `char *` first. Then another implicit conversion to `_Bool` is done according to conversion rules. So no warning. This is similar to `const char *p = "FALSE"; if ( p ) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you print the value of first_time,you will found,the first_time is always 1.
Please see he _Bool here(http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Boolean_type).

you must incude stdbool.h，add use link this:first_time=true;

Comment: you must incude stdbool.h，add use link this:first_time=true;

Comment: An answer should not just provide an external link.